# Anyway to change the default keep-alive close in warp?

Tags: haskell, yesod, haskell-warp

It seems like a keep-alive connection is closed in 60s. Is it possible to configure this in warp?

Comment: Doesn't seem like it https://github.com/yesodweb/wai/issues/734#issuecomment-486552123